# Is there a formula to express the net change in the value of a cell on daily basis?

Tags: excel

Cell A1 = Initial value is 1000. (Calculated from a source list in another sheet).
Cell A2 = Shows the amount that was added in the source list. For example, 200 was added today. Total now is 1200 and change in value is 200. So, A2 shows 200.
Cell A3 = Shows the amount that was taken out of the source list. For example, 150 was subtracted today. So, A3 shows 150.
Cell A4 = Shows the net change which in this case is +50.

Cell A1 changes on daily basis because something is added in and subtracted from the source list on a daily basis. I have to calculate the net change on a daily basis in cell A4.

NOTE: I'm currently working in Google Sheets. But if someone has idea of how to do it in Excel, that's also gonna work for me.

Please help me with the formula or VBA coding to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to be going 88 miles an hour if you want to get yesterday's value after today's value has been entered.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, I didn't quite get you.. Probably you mean to say that there is no way to do this? :)

Comment: When you changes/replace values to any cells, excel doesn't store/remember previous value. So, you can't do that with regular formula. You can can do that by `VBA` macro. So, what you need to do is, preserver previous value of the cell to a variable, then also preserver new value to another variable then subtract one from other.

Comment: @SohailZamani - Sorry, it was a ["Back To The Future"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) reference. You need time travel to get historical figures that have been overwritten. You need to store each day's data without removing the previous days if you want to do what you're asking.

Comment: Harun is right, or change the source sheet to be the actual log, containing a row for each date

Comment: Thanks to all of you for taking the time to answer. Now, I'll have to find a way to create a log in the source sheet. :)

Answer (score 0):

A formula won't help you: it just takes a value and calculates something from that. What you need is an Excel VBA macro, more especially this one:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If (Target.Row = 2) And (Target.Column = 2) Then
  Range("C3").Value = Range("C3").Value + 1
End If
End Sub
```

This increases the value of C3, every time the value of B2 changes.

Beware, the creation of the `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(...)` part is done in the Visual Basic editor (Alt+F11), by double-clicking on the "Sheet" object and by choosing "Change", as you can see in attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "This increases the value of C3, every time the value of B2 changes."
My objective is that everytime the value of B2 changes, C3 returns the increase or decrease of value. 
For example, initial value of B2 is 100 and then I change it to 105, C3 should show 5. Then when I increase the value of B2 to 115, C3 should show 10. 
Don't know if there is a VBA code to achieve this. 
But I really appreciate your contribution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, indeed. As far as I understand, you're looking for such a system, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no Mr. Dominique. :(

Comment: Edit your question and add some data so that your question becomes clear.

Comment: I've edited my post. Kindly see if you can understand my requirement now. Thanks @Dominique.